# Modifying values of existing layer in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control, openlayers-3

I am adding a marker on the map using ol3 by calling the following function

```
function addmarker(lat, long, flag) {

            iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([+long, +lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
                name: 'NULL'
            });

            iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({

                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: '#008000'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#008000',
                    width: 3
                }),
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 6,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#008000'
                    })
                })

            });

            iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

            vectorSource[flag] = new ol.source.Vector({
                features: [iconFeature]
            });

            vectorLayer[flag] = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: vectorSource[flag]
            });

            map.addLayer(vectorLayer[flag]);

        }
```

And to change the marker position, I am removing the layer and adding a new layer again

```
 function changemarker(lat, long, flag) {

             vectorSource[flag].clear();

            map.removeLayer(vectorLayer[flag]);

            addmarker(lat, long, flag);

        }
```

I am facing performance issues as I am changing the marker that is calling the changemarker method every 500 milliseconds.
Can a layer be modified without removing it or is there a better approach that can be followed.

Please help.

Comment: Why is this tagged as C# and WPF?

Comment: I am implementing it using WPF application in a Chromium based webBrowser control. As I am facing performance issue maybe that can be a problem, so I have tagged it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set an ID on a feature `ol.Feature.setId(<your id>)` you can change it directly like so:-

```
//Setting up your feature 
iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([+long, +lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
    name: 'NULL'
});

iconFeature.setId('feature1');
```

Then

```
var myFeature = vectorSource.getFeatureById('feature1');

myFeature.getGeometry().setCoordinates(ol.proj.transform([lon, lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
```

That should update the feature immediately without any redraw calls - OL redraws the layer when a feature is updated.  Using this approach I'm displaying several hundred features with complex geometries on-screen with no major speed penalty.

Comment: This piece of code worked like a charm.. Thank you soo much. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one feature in your layer, you can modify directly the geometry of your feature:

```
function changemarker(lat, long, flag) {

  vectorSource[flag].getFeatures()[0].getGeometry().setCoordinates(ol.proj.transform([+long, +lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
}
```

Comment: Agreed.  If you set an ID on a feature `ol.Feature.setId()` you can change it directly like so.